# Как мне сделать это по DRY

Tags: python, время, python-telegram-bot

```
import telebot
import time

bot = telebot.TeleBot('код')

## Предметы

his = 'История'
ru = 'Русский язык'
ph = 'Физика'
geog = 'География'
al = 'Алгебра'
de = 'Немецкий язык'
geom = 'Геометрия'
che = 'Химия'
bio = 'Биология'
eng = 'Английский язык'
sp = 'Физ-ра'
lit = 'Лит-ра'
p_math = 'Практикум по математике'
inf = 'Информатика'
soc = 'Обществознание'
p_de = 'Практикум по немецкому'

##Скрипт с временем

chat_id_class9b = 'айди'

time_now = time.localtime()

print(time_now.tm_hour, ':', time_now.tm_min)

#Понедельник
if time_now.tm_wday == 0:
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 8) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send0 = his
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send0)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 9) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send0 = ru
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send0)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 10) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send0 = ph
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send0)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 11) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send0 = geog
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send0)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 12) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send0 = de
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send0)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 13) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send0 = al
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send0)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 14) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send0 = geom
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send0)

# Вторник
if time_now.tm_wday == 1:
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 8) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send1 = de
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send1)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 9) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send1 = al
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send1)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 10) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send1 = eng
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send1)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 11) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send1 = che
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send1)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 12) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send1 = bio
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send1)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 13) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send1 = soc
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send1)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 14) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send1 = his
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send1)

# Среда
if time_now.tm_wday == 2:
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 8) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send2 = al
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send2)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 9) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send2 = de
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send2)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 10) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send2 = sp
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send2)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 11) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send2 = ru
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send2)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 12) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send2 = lit
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send2)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 13) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send2 = che
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send2)

# Четверг
if time_now.tm_wday == 3:
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 8) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send3 = geom
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send3)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 9) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send3 = de
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send3)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 10) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send3 = lit
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send3)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 11) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send3 = bio
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send3)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 12) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send3 = inf
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send3)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 13) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send3 = al
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send3)

# Пятница
if time_now.tm_wday == 4:
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 8) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send4 = lit
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send4)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 9) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send4 = ph
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send4)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 10) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send4 = inf
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send4)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 11) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send4 = eng
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send4)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 12) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send4 = geog
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send4)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 13) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send4 = geom
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send4)
    if (time_now.tm_hour == 14) & (time_now.tm_min == 40):
        send4 = sp
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send4)

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
his = 'История'
...

schedule = {
    (0, 8): his,
    ...
}

if time_now.tm_min == 40:
    send0 = schedule.get((time_now.tm_wday, time_now.tm_hour))
    if send0:
        bot.send_message(chat_id_class9b, send0)
```

Заполняете только словарь `schedule` нужными значениями и всё, `if`-ы только эти два, которые у меня в коде, остальные все можно выкинуть. Обратите внимание на двойные скобки у `schedule.get`, это важно! Ключ словаря - кортеж из дня недели и часа, поэтому так.

Структуру словаря можно и другую сделать, например, вложенную - на верхнем уровне день недели, внутри ещё словарь по часам. но это уже детали, принцип работы будет примерно тот же. `DRY` вполне соблюдён.